# Change background/foreground color of powershell variable

Tags: powershell

So i have a powershell script that checks if an IP is available or not, and at the end it counts how many is available and how many not.

Would i be able to change the background/foreground color of the $used & $avail variables?

```
Clear-Host
$Ping = New-Object System.Net.Networkinformation.ping
$IP = Read-Host 'What ip range you want to scan (eg. 192.168.0.)?'
$pused = 0
$pavail = 0
for ($i=1; $i -le 254; $i++)
{
                $Status = $Null
                $IPAddress = $IP + $i
                $Status = ($Ping.Send("$IPAddress", 1)).Status

                if ($Status -eq "TimedOut")
                {
                Write-Host "$IPAddress is available!" -BackgroundColor Green
                $avail = $pavail++
                } else {
                Write-Host "$IPAddress is in USE!" -BackgroundColor Red
                $used = $pused++
                }
}
Write-Host ""
Write-Host $used  -BackgroundColor Red "IPs currently in use" -foregroundcolor "black"
Write-Host ""
Write-Host $avail "IPs currently available" -BackgroundColor Green -foregroundcolor "black"
```

Comment: What are you asking? Have you not already changed the colour? `$used` and `$avail` are also useless, just use `$pused` and `$pavail` throughout.

Comment: why are you using write-host at all? Consider to return an object

Comment: @jisaak what's wrong with using `write-host`? It looks like a simple script that prints information to the screen so I don't why that's wrong in any way.

Comment: I would like to only change the number that `$pused` and `$pavail` return, and not the whole line. Ideally i would like to remove the color of the rest of the line and only change the number it returns. Changed it to only use `$pused` and `$pavail`

Comment: @arco444 http://windowsitpro.com/blog/what-do-not-do-powershell-part-1

Comment: @jisaak you should read your own links. From that: `but it also picks up the ability to write text in specified colors. So I'll temper my "never" with this: Only use Write-Host if your goal is to display some kind of colorful splash screen`. So if OP wants to print colours to the screen, he *has* to use `Write-Host`

Comment: @arco444 I just wanted that the OP consider to use an object which can be reused. Thats all. Imho using colorful outputs is pain for everybody using the script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think to do what you want is by using multiple `Write-Host` lines.

```powershell
Write-Host ""
Write-Host -NoNewline $pused -ForegroundColor Black -BackgroundColor Red
Write-Host " IPs currently in use" 
Write-Host ""
Write-Host -NoNewline $pavail -ForegroundColor Black -BackgroundColor Green
Write-Host " IPs currently available"
```

You can use the `-NoNewline` parameter so that the ouput will still print to the same line in the console.

Comment: that is exactly what i wanted. Thanks. Did not know about the -nonewline parameter :)